# How do I join the anchor point from one path, to an anchor point on another path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have the following:

[image]

I'm trying to create that overlaped look by taking a bit of the path off. I have done so, but the result is two separate paths and I want to have them joined.

As you can see, they are separate paths, and I want to make them into one, but the Click Selected Endpoints button is greyed out for me. I'm not sure how I can join the two.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken here as I am watching the vid on my phone, but it looks like the paths on the top half is closed, so you wont be able to join them with out opening the path again.

You could use pathfinder to join then but that may close up the gap you left, which mean you would have to cut that out or clip mask it.

I would just open the path on the top, then join the different endpoints you require joining.

Comment: Yep, the top half is a closed path. So they can't be joined if one of th paths is closed?

Comment: Based on what I think you're trying to do in the video then nope. Vector paths like to be one continuous path, meaning you can't have multiple paths coming from one anchor point.

 You could try and make them a compound path but the easier and cleaner route for this (in my opinion) would be to open the path, and connect the end points for the top and bottom. In this case I would pick the right side of the path ( coming down at a 45 degree angle from right to left) to the bottom path.